# How to enable underlines and other formattings on a color tty?

Tags: linux, tty, fonts, text-formatting, virtual-consoles

I'm on Arch Linux (a 32 bits alternative version), and recently I've discovered that the blue lines I used to see in Vim with `:set cursorline` were supposed to be underlined, and not blue.

That got me searching all around for a solution.

I'm using no graphical environment, so no desktop environment or window manager, only good ol' tty with `zsh`, my current favorite shell.

I've discovered that `:hi CursorLine cterm=bold` makes the cursor line a lot prettier, as it's now no longer blue, just a lighter color for the most part, and that's already made my life better.

I also tried `cterm=underline` (still renders the line blue), `undercurl`, tried `:hi clear CursorLine` then doing all over again, but nothing brings me the underlines I want.

I tried Vim on `fbterm`, because I believe it's a quasi-graphical terminal emulator, but I got the same behavior, only with an uglier super-wide font.

This not only applies to Vim, but to anything, it seems. I tried ANSI escape sequences on `echo`es, and when trying to underline text, I also got that blue color without underlines.

So I believe *something* is missing, be it a font, a shell config, a Vim config or whatever.

After searching quite a bit, I got no closer to an answer as to why my tty lacks those formatting options, so I decided to ask here.

It's also worth noting that I tried this on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspbian, and I got pretty much the same behavior on the tty.

The only place I managed to get that to work was on the X server I start from time to time to use Firefox. I spawned `xterm` on it and *voila* I got underlines even while typing commands on `zsh`.

I'll now try playing around with different terminal fonts to see if I get any closer to prettifying my tty.

**Edit 01:**

I recorded it with Asciinema, and it shows just fine there, but what I was actually seeing is as I described.
[image: asciicast]

**Edit 02:**

I was reading [this Arch Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications/Utilities#Terminal_emulators) on the section about terminal emulators, and decided to try `yaft`, as it sounded it could be just the thing I was looking for.

It turned out I already had it installed, and using it does indeed enable at least some of the features I wanted, so that's great.

Comment: It's almost certainly capabilities (or a lack of them) in whatever terminal emulator you're using, and/or a mismatched terminal type. What does `echo $TERM` report, and is it correct?

Comment: `echo $TERM` reports `linux`, and as I'm still using Arch's "default" terminal, I believe it's correct.

Comment: @Christopher, I believe your suggestion is to `export TERM=xterm-256color`, correct? I've tried that, confirmed it changed with `echo $TERM`, and still got the blue text instead of underline on both Vim and `echo -e "\033[4munderline\033[0m"`

Comment: @Christopher well, I was first going to ask it on Stack Overflow, but then realized it was more fit for here. And although this issue does also happen on Raspbian, I first spotted it on my laptop running Arch Linux, so I believe it's more about Linux and the tty than anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Linux console driver doesn't support underlines on color displays because it's a compromise between readability and ease of implementation.  It's been that way since the mid 1990s, and is documented in [`console_codes(4)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html):

```
   4       set underscore (simulated with color on a color display)
           (the colors used to simulate dim or underline are set
           using ESC ] ...)
```

It's unlikely that you have anything other than a *color display*.  You can change the color used for depicting underline, but it will be colored one way or another.  The manual page mentions the escape sequence used to customize the *palette*:

```
   ESC ]     OSC      (Should be: Operating system command) ESC ] P
                      nrrggbb: set palette, with parameter given in 7
                      hexadecimal digits after the final P :-(.  Here n
                      is the color (0–15), and rrggbb indicates the
                      red/green/blue values (0–255).  ESC ] R: reset
                      palette
```

and the escape sequences used to tell which of the 16 palette entries will show *dim* and *underline*:

```
   ESC [ 1 ; n ]       Set color n as the underline color.
   ESC [ 2 ; n ]       Set color n as the dim color.
```

Setting `TERM` to any variant of "xterm" will give poor results, because

- Linux console driver lacks support for things that are found in the xterm terminal description, and
- the `linux` terminal description is designed to use the actual features of the Linux console driver.

Use `infocmp linux xterm-256color` to see the differences.  It's long, so here's a summary to show the size of the difference:

```
$ infocmp -1x linux | wc -l
122
$ infocmp -1x xterm-256color |wc -l
272
$ infocmp -1x linux xterm-256color | wc -l
213
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll now begin searching for a way to have a terminal (emulator) that works similar to the one I'm used to, but that has a greater set of features. I'll probably end up running an X server with a simple WM just to keep a virtual terminal open, but if that's the way it has to be, then I think it'll be fine.